# Problema ao chamar função tipo char

Tags: c, string, funções, char

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include<conio.h>

char categoria(char tipo);

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

char str;

printf("Informe a categoria:");

scanf("%s", str);

printf ("A tarifa eh: %s", categoria(str));//DÁ ERRO

return 0;

}

char categoria(char tipo){
    if (tipo=="RS"){
        return 3.02;
    }
}
```

Está dando erro ao chamar a função do tipo char (string).

Comment: Esta  passando uma string como parâmetro para a função categoria.. e  espera 
 passar um char a mesmo retorna um float...  `scanf(" %c", &str); // <-- use %c e & para ler

Comment: `char str;` não é "string", é caractere, não está certo usar `%s`, mas pelo nome que deu a variavel provavelmente você queria mesmo string e não caractere, nesse caso o erro está em como declarou o tipo de str no seu código. Recomendo que antes de fazer o avançado, domine o minimo básico da linguagem lendo alguma documentação, exemplo da IBM, link especifico: https://cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/scanf/ -- Link para um passo a passo: https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/i/7.1?topic=languages-c-c

Comment: Por favor evitem longas discussões nos comentários; a conversa de vocês foi [movida para o chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/142238/discussion-on-question-by-niadjmaod-problema-ao-chamar-funcao-tipo-char)